# Observable is returning each letter of string separately

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, observable

I have some code that sends data to Firebase, waits for a response, then displays the result to the user:

```
sendRequest (data): Observable<any> {
    // Send to Firebase
    const key = this.db.list("Requests").push(data).key

    return this.db.object(`Requests/${key}`).valueChanges().pipe(
        timeout(30000),
        skipWhile(request => !request["response"]), // wait for either response or timeout
        take(1) // stop once a response is received
    )
}

sendOrderRequest(data): Observable<string> {
    return this.sendRequest(data).pipe(
        map(response => {
            // stuff that happens on success
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            if (error.name === "TimeoutError") {
                return "Request timed out."
            } else {
                return "An unknown error occurred."
            }
        })
    )
}

confirmSubmit () {
    this.sendOrderRequest(this.data).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result)
        this.result = result
    }
}
```

It's timing out, but that's not my problem here. My problem is that when it returns the timeout error, it does so one letter at a time - the console displays:

R
e
q
(etc.)

And the data binding in the HTML (`this.result`) only shows the period at the very end. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`catchError` is supposed to return an observable.

```
catchError(error => {
    if (error.name === "TimeoutError") {
        return of("Request timed out.")
    } else {
        return of("An unknown error occurred.")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, figured I was missing something obvious.